# Find $\lim _{x\to 1}\left(\frac{x^n-1}{x^m-1}\right)$

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

So I do know how to find the answer n/m, using l'hopital's rule, but how to find it without using that rule?

$\lim _{x\to 1}\left(\frac{x^n-1}{x^m-1}\right)=\frac{n}{m}$

Comment: use $u^k-1=(u-1)\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} x^i$

Answer (score 3):

Hint:
$$\frac{x^n-1}{x^m-1}=\frac{x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}+\cdots+x+1}{x^{m-1}+x^{m-2}+\cdots+x+1}$$

Comment: still missing it